# Janelas POPUP, como criar?

Tags: javascript

Como faço parar criar uma janela POPUP, que não sejam aquelas que abram uma página na internet?
Preciso de uma que seja parecida com uma DIV, um bloco de quando acessam o site ele aparece antes da pessoa fazer login com algumas informações...

Com um botão de fechá-la também, seria bem útil...

Comment: Então acho que o que você precisa é de um [modal](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/modal/).

Comment: O nome correto de se pronunciar é janela modal? Okay. Obrigado.

Comment: Não sei, veja o link que passei no comentário acima e analise se é isso o que quer.

Comment: O proprio [Jquery UI](https://jqueryui.com/) também tem [janelas modais](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/) assim como existem muitos outros plugins em jQuery/Javascript para isso

Answer (score 1):

Jovem já deu uma olhada nos modals do bootstrap, são bem úteis e fáceis de usar.

Aqui vai o link: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Sobre ao carregar a página você pode fazer uma função e chamar ela no onload da page:

```
window.onload = function(){
    abrirModal(); 
}
```

E aqui um exemplo simples

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A resposta é boa, mas se você colocar o código como texto ao invés de imagem fica melhor.

Comment: É, eu vi depois no bootstrap. Como faço pra criar a função  e chamar no onload da page?

Comment: Simples dentro do onload que eu te passei ali em cima você vai colocar, $("#myModal").modal(); (onde 'myModal' é o ID do seu modal). E pronto ele vai iniciar a tela, carregar e abrir o modal.
**Observação: Pra dar id pra um modal é só colocar a tag id na primeira div da imagem ficando assim (div class ="modal fade" id="myModal"...) **

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente criada com CSS.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".close").click(function(){
        $("#openModal").hide();
    });
});
```

```css
 .modalDialog > div {
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 10% auto;
  padding: 5px 20px 13px 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);
 }

 .close {
  background: #606061;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  line-height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -12px;
  text-align: center;
  top: -10px;
  width: 24px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  -webkit-border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-border-radius: 12px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
 }

 .close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="openModal" class="modalDialog">
 <div>
  <a href="#" class="close" title="Close">X</a>
  <h2>Janela Modal</h2>
  <p>Esta é uma simples janela de modal.</p>
  <p>Você pode fazer qualquer coisa aqui, página de Login, pop-ups, ou formulários</p>
 </div>
</div>
```